# My Vue chrome extension not working in production mode. The error is: "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, google-chrome-extension, vue-cli-3

I am using vue-cli 3.5.1 for my chrome extension. Here is my vue.config.js file:

```
const ChromeExtensionReloader = require('webpack-chrome-extension-reloader')
function setWebpack() {
  let config = {}
  config.plugins = [
    new ChromeExtensionReloader({
      entries: {
        background: 'background.js'
      }
    })
  ]
  config.entry = {
    background: './src/background.js',
    inpage: './src/inpage.js'
  }
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    config.output = {
      filename: 'js/[name].js',
      chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js'
    }
  }
  return config
}
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: setWebpack(),
  filenameHashing: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: 'src/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
    },
    notification: {
      entry: 'src/main.js',
      template: 'public/notification.html',
      filename: 'notification.html'
    }
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "@/styles/index.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Everything works in 'development' mode, but not in 'production' mode.

I think the problem is in the background.js file. It is not executing correctly. You can look at the file below.

The fe77 method seems to be never executed. I put a console log inside it, and there was nothing in my browser console. Also I replaced the content of compiled background.js with the raw code from my src folder and everything worked. No errors. I have tried to google this problem, but it no luck, since it's not that much about writing chrome extensions with vue cli 3... Any help would be much appreciated.

My background.js output in production mode ():

```
(function (e) {
  function r(r) {
    for (var n, c, i = r[0], a = r[1], s = r[2], l = 0, p = []; l < i.length; l++) c = i[l], o[c] && p.push(o[c][0]), o[c] = 0;
    for (n in a) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a, n) && (e[n] = a[n]);
    f && f(r);
    while (p.length) p.shift()();
    return u.push.apply(u, s || []), t()
  }

  function t() {
    for (var e, r = 0; r < u.length; r++) {
      for (var t = u[r], n = !0, i = 1; i < t.length; i++) {
        var a = t[i];
        0 !== o[a] && (n = !1)
      }
      n && (u.splice(r--, 1), e = c(c.s = t[0]))
    }
    return e
  }

  var n = {}, o = {background: 0}, u = [];

  function c(r) {
    if (n[r]) return n[r].exports;
    var t = n[r] = {i: r, l: !1, exports: {}};
    return e[r].call(t.exports, t, t.exports, c), t.l = !0, t.exports
  }

  c.e = function () {
    return Promise.resolve()
  }, c.m = e, c.c = n, c.d = function (e, r, t) {
    c.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, {enumerable: !0, get: t})
  }, c.r = function (e) {
    "undefined" !== typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {value: "Module"}), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {value: !0})
  }, c.t = function (e, r) {
    if (1 & r && (e = c(e)), 8 & r) return e;
    if (4 & r && "object" === typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e;
    var t = Object.create(null);
    if (c.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", {
      enumerable: !0,
      value: e
    }), 2 & r && "string" != typeof e) for (var n in e) c.d(t, n, function (r) {
      return e[r]
    }.bind(null, n));
    return t
  }, c.n = function (e) {
    var r = e && e.__esModule ? function () {
      return e["default"]
    } : function () {
      return e
    };
    return c.d(r, "a", r), r
  }, c.o = function (e, r) {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r)
  }, c.p = "/";
  var i = window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || [], a = i.push.bind(i);
  i.push = r, i = i.slice();
  for (var s = 0; s < i.length; s++) r(i[s]);
  var f = a;
  u.push(["fe77", "chunk-vendors", "chunk-common"]), t()
})({
  fe77: function (e, r, t) {
    "use strict";
    t.r(r);
    t("cadf"), t("551c"), t("f751"), t("097d");
    var n = {pass: "123123"};
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (e, r, t) {
      var o = r.url || r.tab.url, u = /^chrome-extension/.test(o);
      if (!u) return "getNetAddress" === e.type ? (chrome.storage.local.get("currentNet", function (e) {
        var r = e.currentNet;
        t({type: "netAddress", address: r})
      }), !0) : (chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL("notification.html"), active: !1}, function (n) {
        chrome.windows.create({tabId: n.id, type: "popup", focused: !0, width: 400, height: 600}, function () {
          e.sender = r, console.log(e), setTimeout(function () {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(e, function (e) {
              if (chrome.runtime.lastError) return console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
              t(e)
            })
          }, 1e3)
        })
      }), !0);
      switch (e.type) {
        case"setState":
          return void (n[e.prop] = e.data);
        case"getState":
          return void t(n[e.prop]);
        default:
          return
      }
    })
  }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=background.js.map
```

expected: background.js should work in both development and production modes.
actual: background.js works only in development mode

UPD1 This is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "web-wallet",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Nerthus web wallet extension",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "*://*/",
    "notifications",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost:8098; object-src 'self'",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "logo/16.png",
      "32": "logo/32.png",
      "48": "logo/48.png",
      "128": "logo/128.png"
    }
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "file://*/*",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "js/inpage.js",
    "backend.js"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: That's the whole point... You don't want people being able to play with your vue state easily in production.

Comment: @Trent, Do you mean that there are some vue specific rules in @vue/cli webpack config that cause this problem in my script?

Comment: You didn't show manifest.json which is one of the most important parts of an extension. I guess you have persistent: false there, and your webpack output wraps the original background script in a Promise, but API listeners must be registered synchronously on each run of the background script, otherwise they're ignored.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Thank you for your reply. I added my manifest.json and yes, persistent is set to false. I tried to change it to true, but I still get the same error. I have also tried to use webpack-cli to process my background.js without any vue config. It worked. And there was no Promise in the output file. But I can't figure out how to get rid of promises in vue-cli output...I need to mention that I have no promises in my background.js source code. Only callbacks.

Comment: Assuming you reloaded the extension on chrome://extensions page after making the changes, it would seem a problem with configuring webpack/vue, which I haven't used so can't help. BTW why do you even use Vue in the background script? It runs in a hidden background page that's never shown to the user.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you gave me some hints. Actually I don't use anything from vue in background.js, but I want it to be processed by webpack. And also the "webpack-chrome-extension-reloader" plugin requires background.js to be in webpack entry. Unfortunately, vue-cli provides it's own vue.config.js file for adding custom settings into their webpack configuration.